# next_post_link() - how to add url parameter

Tags: next-post-link

How can i append some url parameters to the next_post_link?
Forexample "?objectcat=someCategoryName"

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'nächstes Ojekt', TRUE, '$url_object_categorie', 'cat_objects' ); ?>
```